# using expr with strings

Tags: scripts

`y=$(expr  "$str" : ".*$x" - length "$x")`  can anyone please explain this piece of code.
I am new to scripting and have some experience with c++ and python.
Actually this question was a part of my comment to one of my previous question but I am not getting any answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `expr` expression `"$str" : ".*$x"` is a regular expression match. The general form is

```
expr STRING : REGEXP
```

where `REGEXP` is an *anchored regular expression* - "anchored" meaning that it attempts to match `REGEX` starting from the first character of `STRING`, so in order to match `$x` anywhere inside `$str` you need something like `.*` to slurp up all the characters from the anchor to the start of `$x`

The result is the length of the matched pattern - that includes everything matched by `.*` as well as everything matched by `$x`. So

```
expr  "$str" : ".*$x" - length "$x"
```

returns the starting index of the match of `$x` in `$str`, or minus the length of `$x` if no match is found. So for example:

```
$ expr foobarbaz : ".*bar" - length bar
3

$ expr foobar : ".*baz" - length baz
-3
```

Note that although you may be "using `expr` with strings", it will actually interpret `$x` as an (GNU basic) regular expression - so be careful if it contains anything other than alphanumeric characters.

Comment: why does it sucks if I use `$(expr index $string $char)`     it gives proper answer if the string is without space but gives absurd result with strings with space. ex: `$(expr index "foo bar biz ball bag bus"  "biz")`

Comment: @FreeDown that's really a different question (`index` versus `match`): the second argument of `expr index` is neither a string nor a regex, it's a *set of characters*, and the `index` function returns the first (i.e. numerically lowest) index of the occurrence in `$string` of *any of the characters from the set* `$char`. In your example it would return the index of the `b` in `bar`.